# Can't get JavaFX Separator to style with a different color

Tags: java, css, javafx, separator

All I am trying to do, is add a separator in between elements in a VBox, but I want the separator line to be a different color than the default. Let's chose red for example.

The only CSS I could find that would change the line color is this:

```
.separator {
    -fx-padding: 8;
}

.separator .line {
    -fx-background-color: red;
    -fx-pref-height: 5;
}
```

But that seems to add a second line and it does not color the primary line as you can see here:

[image]

It needs to look like this:

[image]

Here is a working example showing the problem. If you run this code, you will need to add this to your POM file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.simtechdata</groupId>
    <artifactId>Switcher</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

And create a CSS file called Separator.css and place it in the resources folder. The contents of the css file are already in this post (the first code snipped that I posted).

Here is the running class:

```
package sample;

import com.simtechdata.Switcher;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Separator;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    private final       ClassLoader resource       = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        String separatorCSS = resource.getResource("Separator.css").toExternalForm();        AnchorPane ap = new AnchorPane();
        ap.setPrefWidth(300);
        ap.setPrefHeight(400);
        Switcher.addScene(10,ap,300,400);
        ap.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black");
        Label label1 = new Label("Example Text");
        Label label2 = new Label("More Example Text");
        label1.setStyle("\t-fx-font-size: 24pt;\n" +
                       "\t-fx-font-family: \"Segoe UI Semibold\";\n" +
                       "\t-fx-text-fill: rgb(255,155,0);\n" +
                       "\t-fx-alignment: center;\n");
        label2.setStyle("\t-fx-font-size: 24pt;\n" +
                       "\t-fx-font-family: \"Segoe UI Semibold\";\n" +
                       "\t-fx-text-fill: rgb(255,155,0);\n" +
                       "\t-fx-alignment: center;\n");
        Separator separator = new Separator();
        separator.getStylesheets().add(separatorCSS);
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label1,separator,label2);
        ap.getChildren().add(vbox);
        Switcher.showScene(10);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to change the color of a JavaFX Separator line either programmatically or by using CSS?

Thank you,

Mike Sims

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a `Separator` [has a border](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css#L1147) (for a horizontal separator the border is on the top). This is the white line you're seeing.

Just remove the border, e.g.:

```css
.separator .line {
    -fx-background-color: red;
    -fx-pref-height: 5;
    -fx-border-color: null ;
}
```

Comment: That worked. But why, when I do not style a color for the line, is the border the only "line" that shows up by default? It is certainly not obvious when using a Seperator, that you would then have to remove the boarder and style the line before you actually get a single line.

Comment: @MichaelSims “why… is the border the only line I see”. It’s not. The border is one pixel wide and is a subtly different colour to the background. This gives it a 3D effect. Obviously, if you change the background to red, the difference is no longer subtle.

Comment: My point is, I am here seeking knowledge. It is perfectly acceptable to correct me where I am wrong because that's why I'm here. People cannot see a closed question, so I modified it for clarity and re-posted it AS THE SITE SUGGESTED THAT I DO - so doing that is not wrong, it is encouraged. And the Separator object is still obtuse. It is not obvious nor intuitive to use.  When I create a separator and merely set the prefHeight, all it does is expand the space around it, but it leaves a thin line in the center, the border as you point out, which offers no 3d look to anything by default.

Comment: I also need to point out that I have never once stated nor implied anything about the library doing something "stupid".  If you read my post, I merely state the behavior that I am seeing with the library, then I ask how I can make it do what I need it to do. The implication that I am judging the library is solely your opinion but it is wrong and I never said anything that would give that impression.

Comment: And to see that posting a new question is encouraged, here is a screen shot of what the site actually says when your question is closed: https://i.imgur.com/kyjZcHQ.png

Comment: @MichaelSims *”it leaves a thin line in the center, the border as you point out”*. No. You keep missing the point. You are seeing *both* the border *and* the line (whose color is controlled by `.separator .line { -fx-background-color : … ; }`). The color of the border is only very subtly different to the color of the line by default (and both of them are gradients, making them harder to distinguish visually).  If you change the color of the line to red, then the difference is obvious, but you are still looking at the same two things you were always looking at.

Comment: Well, when I change the line color, as you can see in the screenshot I posted, it LOOKS like one line stacked on top of another line. A border is supposed to surround an object, and the line that you keep insisting is a border, does not, in fact, surround the actual line.

Comment: @MichaelSims And as I said in a previous comment, the border width is set to positive for the top only. Where do you get the idea that a border has to be on all four sides? That is not the common usage of the word, either in computing or in general usage.

Comment: The common usage of the term border in the context of graphics carries with it the implication of a line that surrounds the image. The concept of a border in the context of geography is a line that divides two locations.